# Hello, World. Speech Recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition

How can I make this program display a simple Hello World message when I say Hello World?  I want to make this program into a speech recognition application that displays what I say onto the screen of cell phone running android 2.1 or later.

so far this is what I have:

```
    // **** SpeechRecognition.java  *****
    package com.SpeechRecognition.CMPE4373;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.*; 
     import android.os.Handler;

     import android.speech.*;
     import android.inputmethodservice.*;

     public class SpeechRecognition extends Activity {
     /*  Declaring variables  */
   private static final String TAG = "VoiceRecognition";
   private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
   private ListView mList;
   private Handler mHandler;
   private Spinner mSupportedLanguageView;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mHandler = new Handler();

         }
      }





<!--               layout/main.xml          -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>




<!--              AndroidManifest.xml          -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.SpeechRecognition.CMPE4373"

 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SpeechRecognition" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) is exactly, what you are searching for.
You have it already in your api-samples inside the Android-Sdk

Comment: Do you know what lines of code I need to create a text field that displays "Hello World" when I speak on the microphone using the same code above?

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-